# mongodb $facet unaccepted result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am runing this query on local db :

```
db.designations.aggregate([{
$facet:{
    data:[
        {
            $match:{
                status:{
                    $in:['ACTIVE']
                }
            }
        }
        ]
}}] )
```

But the result format is very different :

```
{
"data" : [
    {
        "data" : "s\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003obj\u0000i\u0000\u0000\u0000\n_id\u0000\u0010__v\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002status\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000ACTIVE\u0000\u0007departmentId\u0000[YêÑPÞ%$;Wut\u0002description\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0002name\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0000\u0000"
    },
    {
        "data" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003obj\u0000u\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007_id\u0000[YëAGÛ¼%«wþX\u0002name\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0002description\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0002status\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000ACTIVE\u0000\u0007departmentId\u0000[YêÑPÞ%$;Wut\u0010__v\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
    },
    {
        "data" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003obj\u0000u\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007_id\u0000[YëAGÛ¼%«wþY\u0002name\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0002description\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0002status\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0000ACTIVE\u0000\u0007departmentId\u0000[YêÑPÞ%$;Wut\u0010__v\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
    }
]}
```

Can anyone explain this.??
that will be very helpfull

Comment: this is not the issue with `$facet`, your data is in encoded form... Post your sample collection of `designations`

Comment: I found the solution it was encoded by client robomongo..

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem, I just changed `data` key to something else, e.g. `data1`, and it worked for me. You can verify by the query below:

```
db.designations.aggregate([{
    $facet:{
        data1:[
            {
                $match:{
                    status:{
                        $in:['ACTIVE']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}]);
```